# lwjgl 101: How can I write the basics?

Tags: java, lwjgl

EDIT: So apparently I was doing everything right, but I had a different problem that made it look as if I was doing something wrong. Sorry about that. --me, newbie

This ought to be really simple, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to compile anything with lwjgl and have it work. I can write something like

```
package gwison;

import org.lwjgl.Sys;

public class G
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Sys.getTime());
    }
}
```

and I can easily compile a program with several classes in different packages, as long as I wrote all the classes myself. But I have no clue how to make G work. I think it has something to do with classpathes? Maybe? Help?

I really have been searching for hours, but the most basic tutorials assume you know how to do this!

Edit: oh and I'm sorry if I've violated stackoverflow conventions; I did try not to but this is my first action here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to make sure the jars are in the classpath while compiling and running.
Place your lwjgl jars in the classpath during compilation 
More info :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29

Comment: That really doesn't help at all... "I really have been searching for hours." Sorry.

Comment: Assuming your jar is lwjgl.jar, then you first need to compile your java file.Assuming lwjgl is in current directory:



javac -classpath lwjgl.jar gwison/G.java

Comment: Turns out that I was doing the right thing all along, at least with the classpath. The problem I'm having comes from an ENTIRELY different source.

Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this way create a folder called TestProject inside it create one folder 
gwison like D:\TestProject\gwison
Create two more folder in same TestFolder like this D:\TestProject\org\lwjgl.
Now create a Class G in gwison folder like u created above.Create one more class Sys like this

```
package org.lwjgl;
import java.util.Date;
public class Sys {
        public static Date getTime(){
            return new Date();
        }
}
```

now from command promt go to this path D:\TestFolder and run the below command:

```
javac gwison\G.java
```

This will complie your code, now run one more command:

```
java gwison.G
```

This will run your code without any error and you will get a output like this:

```
Sun May 02 13:17:11 IST 2010
```

Comment: What? I'm trying to use the pre-existent library lwgjl.